# How to sort through WebElements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to come up with a script/for-loop that will locate all input elements on the form and depending the the **type** of the input will send string/number keys or perform select class

So i got my createForm :

```
<form id="createForm" class="submit-form" method="post" action="/BusinessAccount/82">
```

and example of the element :

```
<input id="ReferralDate" class="form-control text-box single-line" type="datetime" value="" name="ReferralDate">
```

so what i got so far is :

```
elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value =".//*[@id='createForm']//div//input") 

for element in elements:
    if element.tag_name == 'datetime':
        element.send_keys('11/11/2011')
```

won't get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `get_attribute` then the code may something like this

```
for element in elements:
    if element.get_attribute('type') == 'datetime':
        element.send_keys('11/11/2011')
```

Comment: worked. Helped me to get rid of 'hidden' elements as well. thanks

Comment: Great! Happy to hear!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You first check by giving some date value in to the input field the format how it is taking the Date is it like

```
(dd-mm-yyyy)
```

or

```
(dd/mm/yyyy)
```

or

```
(mm/dd/yyyy)
```

or

```
(mm-dd-yyyy)
```

or

```
(yyyy-mm-dd)
```

Depending on the format of string it is taking, pass the value accordingly.

Hope it helps.